# Looping through Outlook Contacts and Checking Dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary, outlook, office365, contacts

My code is intended to loop through all Outlook contacts, create a dictionary object containing their email addresses and phone numbers, and then check a selected email for client information.

The email contains subscription requests, and I want to cross-reference this information with the dictionary to determine if the subscribers are in my contacts.

The problem is sometimes the code shows "Already Existing" for email addresses that aren't in my contacts. I manually verified that those email addresses are not present.

```vb
Option Explicit

'Change below path with the path of the folder that will be deduped
'Public Const strContactFolder As String = "\\youremail@xyz.com\Contacts\SourceContacts"
Public Const strContactFolder As String = "\\youremail@xyz.com\Contacts"

'Change below path with the path of the folder that will contains duplicate contacts
'Public Const strDupeFolder As String = "\\youremail@xyz.com\Contacts\DuplicateContacts"
Public Const strDupeFolder As String = "\\TM Contacts\DuplicateContacts"

'Change below path with the path of the folder that will contains duplicate contacts
'Public Const strMissingFolder As String = "\\youremail@xyz.com\Contacts\MissingInfo"
Public Const strMissingFolder As String = "\\TM Contacts\MissingInfo"

Public bolDedupe As Boolean
Sub AddSubs_Match_with_4Keys_4()

    'Duplicate criteria _
    '--> Cross Matching with: _
    'Home# _
    'Mobile# _
    'Other# _
    'Email _
    'Email2

    Dim oContactFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oDictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cObject As Object
    Dim oItem As Outlook.ContactItem
        
        Dim stPhone_Key As String, stMobile_Key As String, stOther_Key As String
        Dim stEmail_Key As String, stEmail2_Key As String

    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set oContactFolder = SetMyFolder(strContactFolder, False)

    If oContactFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Source contact folder can't be found", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To oContactFolder.Items.Count
        Set cObject = oContactFolder.Items.Item(i)

        If TypeOf cObject Is Outlook.ContactItem Then
            
            Set oItem = cObject

            'other
            If oItem.HomeTelephoneNumber <> "" Then
            
                stPhone_Key = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(oItem.HomeTelephoneNumber, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
                oDictionary(stPhone_Key) = True
            End If

            'Contact
            If oItem.MobileTelephoneNumber <> "" Then
                
                stMobile_Key = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(oItem.MobileTelephoneNumber, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
                oDictionary(stMobile_Key) = True
            End If
            
            'Other
            If oItem.OtherTelephoneNumber <> "" Then
                
                stOther_Key = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(oItem.OtherTelephoneNumber, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
                oDictionary(stOther_Key) = True
            End If

            'Email
            If oItem.Email1Address <> "" Then
                    
                stEmail_Key = Replace(LCase(oItem.Email1Address), " ", "")
                oDictionary(stEmail_Key) = True
            End If

            '2nd Email
            If oItem.Email2Address <> "" Then
                                
                stEmail2_Key = Replace(LCase(oItem.Email2Address), " ", "")
                oDictionary(stEmail2_Key) = True
            End If
                            
        End If 'Contacts
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling to default

    If oDictionary.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Something wrong with the dictionary section!", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim CSVLine As String
    Dim SelectedMails As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oMail In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(oMail) = "MailItem" Then
            If InStr(1, oMail.Subject, "has subscribed to", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Update_Contact_Info oMail, oDictionary, CSVLine
                
            End If
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    SelectedMails = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

'*** CSV OR MSG
    Dim CSVFilePath As String
    Dim CSVFile As Object
    
    CSVFilePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") _
                                            & "\output.csv"
    
' Check if the CSV file is open and close it if needed
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CSVFile = GetObject(CSVFilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not CSVFile Is Nothing Then
        CSVFile.Close
        Set CSVFile = Nothing
    End If
' ---

    Set CSVFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") _
                 .CreateTextFile(CSVFilePath, True)
    With CSVFile
        .WriteLine "First Name,Last Name,Spouse,Email,Contact/Husband No,Wife No,Other No,Status"
        .WriteLine CSVLine
        .Close
    End With
    
    If SelectedMails < 11 Then
            
        CSVLine = Replace(CSVLine, ",", " ")
        MsgBox CSVLine, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, SelectedMails & " Mail(s) are processed"
    
    End If

End Sub
Sub Update_Contact_Info(olMail As Outlook.MailItem, oDictionary As Object, CSVLine As String)

    Dim strBody As String
    Dim dKey As Variant
    
    Dim stFirst As String
    Dim stLast As String
    Dim stEmail As String
    Dim stSpouse As String
    Dim stAddress As String
    
    Dim stContact As String 'Husband
    Dim stWifeNum As String 'Wife
    Dim stOther As String   'Other
    

    'Outlook objects
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oContactFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oContact As Outlook.ContactItem

    'HTML Parsing
    Dim t0 As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, tKey As String, tVal As String, t1 As Object
    Dim iHtml As New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim dictTable As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dictTable = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    dictTable.CompareMode = TextCompare
    iHtml.Body.innerHTML = olMail.HTMLBody
    
    strBody = ""
    Set t0 = iHtml.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each tr In t0
        Set t1 = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
        tKey = ""
        tVal = ""
        For Each td In t1
            If tKey = "" Then
                tKey = LCase(Trim(Replace(td.innerText, ":", "", , , vbTextCompare)))
            Else
                tVal = Trim(td.innerText)
            End If
        Next
        
        strBody = strBody & vbCrLf & tKey & "" & tVal
        dictTable.Add tKey, tVal
    Next
    
    Dim bSingle As Boolean
        
    If dictTable.Exists("first name") = True And dictTable.Exists("last name") = True Then
        stFirst = dictTable("first name")
        stLast = dictTable("last name")
        bSingle = True
    ElseIf dictTable.Exists("husband first name") = True And dictTable.Exists("husband last name") = True Then
        stFirst = dictTable("husband first name")
        stLast = dictTable("husband last name")
        bSingle = False
    Else
        CSVLine = CSVLine & olMail.Subject & ",,,,,,," & "Unrecognized Email body" & vbCr
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
 
'Addressing
    Dim sAddr2 As String
    stAddress = ""
    sAddr2 = ""
    For Each dKey In dictTable.Keys
        Select Case dKey
            Case "address"
                stAddress = dictTable(dKey)
            Case "city", "state", "zip"
                sAddr2 = sAddr2 & IIf(Len(sAddr2) > 0, ", ", "") & dictTable(dKey)
        End Select
    Next
    If Len(sAddr2) > 0 Then stAddress = stAddress & "," & vbCrLf & sAddr2
    
    
    If bSingle = False Then
    
        If dictTable.Exists("email") = True Then stEmail = dictTable("email")
        If dictTable.Exists("wife first name") = True Then stSpouse = dictTable("wife first name")
        If dictTable.Exists("wife last name") = True Then stSpouse = Trim(stSpouse & " " & dictTable("wife last name"))
        
        If dictTable.Exists("husband phone no.") = True Then
            stContact = dictTable("husband phone no.")
            stContact = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(stContact, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
        End If
        
        If dictTable.Exists("wife phone no.") = True Then
            stWifeNum = dictTable("wife phone no.")
            stWifeNum = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(stWifeNum, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
        End If
        
        If dictTable.Exists("other phone no.") = True Then
            stOther = dictTable("other phone no.")
            stOther = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(stOther, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
        End If
        
        GoTo MatchingWithDictionary
        
    End If

    
'Single
    If dictTable.Exists("email") = True Then stEmail = dictTable("email")
    If dictTable.Exists("spouse name") = True Then stSpouse = dictTable("spouse name")
    
    If dictTable.Exists("contact phone") = True Then
        stContact = dictTable("contact phone")
        stContact = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(stContact, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
    End If
    
    If dictTable.Exists("other phone") = True Then
        stOther = dictTable("other phone")
        stOther = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(stOther, "(", ""), ")", ""), "-", ""), " ", "")
    End If


MatchingWithDictionary:
    
    If oDictionary.Exists(stEmail) = True _
    Or oDictionary.Exists(stOther) = True _
    Or oDictionary.Exists(stContact) = True _
    Then
        CSVLine = CSVLine & stFirst & "," & stLast & "," & stSpouse & "," & stEmail & "," & _
                                         stContact & "," & stWifeNum & "," & stOther & "," & "Already Exist" & vbCr
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'Add to Contacts
    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oContactFolder = SetMyFolder(strContactFolder, False)
    Set oContact = oContactFolder.Items.Add(olContactItem)
    
    With oContact
        .FirstName = stFirst
        .LastName = stLast
        .Email1Address = stEmail
        .Spouse = stSpouse
        .HomeAddress = stAddress
        .MobileTelephoneNumber = stContact  'Husband
        .HomeTelephoneNumber = stWifeNum    'Wife
        .OtherTelephoneNumber = stOther     'Other
        .MessageClass = "IPM.Contact.Tiferes Miriam Contacts"
        .Save
    End With
    
    CSVLine = CSVLine & stFirst & "," & stLast & "," & stSpouse & "," & stEmail & "," & _
                                     stContact & "," & stWifeNum & "," & stOther & "," & "New Contact Added" & vbCr

End Sub

Function SetMyFolder(ByVal FolderPath As String, ByVal bolShared As Boolean) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder         As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray    As Variant
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim SubFolders      As Outlook.Folders
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set oApp = Outlook.Application
    Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    
    On Error GoTo SetMyFolder_Error
    If bolShared = True Then
        Set oFolder = oNS.Folders(FoldersArray(0))
        If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
                Set oFolder = oFolder.Folders(FoldersArray(i))
                If oFolder Is Nothing Then Set SetMyFolder = Nothing
            Next
        End If
        
        'Return the oFolder
        Set SetMyFolder = oFolder
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If bolShared = False Then
        Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
        If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
                Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
                Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
                If oFolder Is Nothing Then Set SetMyFolder = Nothing
            Next
        End If
        'Return the oFolder
        Set SetMyFolder = oFolder
        Exit Function
    End If
        
SetMyFolder_Error:
    Set SetMyFolder = Nothing
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: There is an e-mail address in your code, I hope it's a dummy one and not an existing one?

Comment: Have you checked which data lead to the message "Already Existing"? (not only email addresses are evaluated for this)

Comment: @Shrotter it maybe dictionary adding wrong entries? yes I have searched the email, as well as the phone numbers, both does not exist in the contacts but the macro shows "already exist". what should I do instead of dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried to set there a breaking point and check data that resolves the conflict (and check the values in the dictionary)?

Comment: You have a lot of `On Error Resume Next` in there - maybe try commenting some of those out and then see what happens.